# subclass consists of various elements of its superclass

Tags: inheritance, uml

i am currently trying to design a uml class diagramm for a simple application i'm developing.
The Problem: I have a class, that is a subclass and another subclass of the same superclass. The first one, lets call it `subclass1` consists of various elements of the superclass, that is itself and the other `subclass2`.

Now i'm not sure how to model this correctly in UML. The following two pictures show the two possibilities i've come up with. Both don't seem correct tbh.

[image: Option1]

Option 1: `subclass1` is an aggregation of it's superclass.

[image: Option2]

Option 2: `subclass2` contains a list of superclass elements

My Question: Is one of these correct and if not, how would i model it correctly?

Comment: On the option1 diagram your aggregation diamond is on the wrong side. Now this indicates that the `superclass1` has a relation to a set of `subclass1`. That is clearly wrong as a superclass should never know about its subclasses.

Comment: If written inline (Option 2), the attribute should also use proper UML notation, so instead of `+list: List<Superclass1>` it should be `+list: Superclass1[*]`. I'm not providing it as answer as  Thomas Killian already provided the correct one, just this single information is missing in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically both diagrams are the same. You are using a shared aggregation in the first where you intend to express multiplicity. This is not correct. Shared aggregation has an open semantic to be defined in the context of a domain.

[image]

The picture above would be the preferred way. It uses an association with multiplicity and a role name. This is semantically identical to your second picture.

N.B. I used upper case for the class names as this is a common convention.

Comment: @SgtDroelf are you trying to use the composite pattern ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: @granier Argh. Those Wiki guys use the shared composition.

Comment: Yes I see, but Wikipedia stays a simple reference ... I will check this night at home, but I am quite sure that in Gamma's book a shared composition is used ...

Comment: @granier That book is from 2005 and the shared composition has been specified to be domain specific only in new UML versions.

Comment: yes indeed ;) it is why the Wikipedia page could be accepted ... and as you said on a previous post : most of the people do not master the difference between shared composition and composition.